# Why NSLineBreakByWordWrapping splits word?

Tags: ios, line-breaks, nsattributedstring

With using NSAttributedString, I tried to create text inside a triangle as below;

http://postimg.org/image/rp9fukgaj/

I used "NSLineBreakByWordWrapping" method for fitting text inside defined shape. But first word of text splits and I couldn't found a solution for that. I want my text jumps to the following line instead of splitting. How can I do that?

Below the code I used;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    CTFontRef fontRef = CTFontCreateWithName((CFStringRef)@"HelveticaNeue-Regular", 15.0f, NULL);     
    NSMutableParagraphStyle* paragraph = [NSMutableParagraphStyle new];
    paragraph.headIndent = 10;
    paragraph.firstLineHeadIndent = 10;
    paragraph.tailIndent = -10;
    paragraph.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    paragraph.alignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    paragraph.paragraphSpacing = 15;    
    NSDictionary *attrDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: (__bridge id)fontRef, (NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, (id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (NSString *)(kCTForegroundColorAttributeName),paragraph,NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];    
    CFRelease(fontRef);
    NSAttributedString *attString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Initially, now I create the paragraph style and apply it to the first character. Note how the margins are dictated: the tailIndent is negative, to bring the right margin leftward, and the firstLineHeadIndent must be set separately, as the headIndent does not automatically apply to the first line." attributes:attrDictionary];
    [(CustomView *)[self view] setAttString:attString];
}
```

Comment: Since you know the first word won't fit, start with a paragraph break to move everything down. You could draw with Text Kit and override the layout manager, of course, to prevent this from happening (or you could let it hyphenate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSParagraphStyle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSLineBreakMode) for NSLineBreakMode, apparently if the word will not fit on a given line, the word will get broken up to fit. If your text is static, you could probably just insert a newline character to skip the first part of the triangle; otherwise, you'll have to be clever to figure out how to overcome this limitation.

Comment: I overcame this problem with inserting a newline character. With simple first word length algorithm, I managed this issue. I know it is not the best solution but it worked in my case. Thank you for answering my post.